# Google autocomplete Restrictions more than 1 country

Tags: api, autocomplete

Is it possible to filter for more than 1 country?

I tried this:

```
componentRestrictions: {country: "us","uk"}
```

but that didnt worked.

complete code:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize() {
      var options = { 
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us","uk"}
 };

 var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

}

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
componentRestrictions: {country: "us", country: "ca"}
```

its works like charm :)